# Django admin giving internal server error 500

Tags: django, django-admin

My django and python knowledge is not very deep. I followed the Django tutorial (1.7) and then created an app for someone to update a list of people via the django admin. I have it working locally, and it works as well on my staging server.

On production, the site works, and I can get to the admin log in page. But when I log in, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. I've spent about two days trying to debug this.

The Apache error log shows "[Errno 111] Connection refused" but lots of googling that text has turned up nothing I can use yet.

Based on some of the related conversations I've found on here,they seem to focus on using django to send email (I'm not).

I think I've got my Allowed Hosts configured correctly, since I can see the non-admin site.

I've compared the apache configs and file permissions between the staging server and the production server, and they all seem to be the same.

Any help you may be able to offer would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**error.log**

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664] mod_wsgi (pid=26646): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/admin/dj-1.7/accountedge/trunk/accountedge/accountedge/wsgi.py'., referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/home/admin/dj-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     response = self.get_response(request), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/home/admin/dj-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 199, in get_response, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info()), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/home/admin/dj-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 231, in handle_uncaught_exception, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     'request': request, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1178, in error, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1271, in _log, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     self.handle(record), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1281, in handle, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     self.callHandlers(record), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1321, in callHandlers, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     hdlr.handle(record), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 749, in handle, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     self.emit(record), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/home/admin/dj-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 132, in emit, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     connection=self.connection()), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/home/admin/dj-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 98, in mail_admins, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     mail.send(fail_silently=fail_silently), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/home/admin/dj-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 286, in send, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self]), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/home/admin/dj-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 92, in send_messages, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     new_conn_created = self.open(), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/home/admin/dj-1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 50, in open, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 311, in connect, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 286, in _get_socket, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout), referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664]     raise err, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
[wsgi:error] [pid 26646:tid 140557972109056] [client xx.xx.xxx.xx:57664] error: [Errno 111] Connection refused, referer: ***.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/
```

**settings.py**

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
from os import path
import socket
from os.path import dirname
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'x'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
if socket.gethostname().startswith('x'):
    DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
else:
    DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '.accountedge.com',
    'accountedge.com',
    'localhost',
    '162.209.1.124',
    '162.209.4.135',
]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'geoip',
    'localflavor',
    'partners',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'accountedge.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'accountedge.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accountedge/templates'),
)

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

ADMINS = (
    ('ed', 'x'),
)

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static-root/')

## local
if socket.gethostname().startswith('x'):
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
## staging: rackspace
elif socket.gethostname() == 'rerun-mktg':
    STATIC_URL = 'http://x/accountedge/staging/rackspace/static/'
## PRODUCTION
else:
    STATIC_URL = 'http://x/accountedge/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('', path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static')),
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'geoip.context.maxmind',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.load_template_source',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `send_mail()` somewhere and you haven't specified any setting for mail. You can see [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/) for more details on this.

Comment: While I wasn't using send_mail() anywhere, I followed your advice and added an email backend. Then when I tried again it I was emailed the trace that told me: `OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database` and that solved the issue. Thanks for your help!